# How to parameterize CSS selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

May be the question title is bit confusing, but to give a specific example

```
body.page-status .panel.panel-info .server .dot {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

I also want this rule to apply for

```
body.page-status .panel.panel-info .client .dot {
  font-size:10px;
}
```

If you see closely, the only difference between 2 selectors is `.server` and `.client`

Can I combine them in 1 rule somehow?

Thanks

Comment: `body.page-status .panel.panel-info .server .dot, body.page-status .panel.panel-info .client .dot {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [comma to group selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping):

```
body.page-status .panel.panel-info .server .dot,
body.page-status .panel.panel-info .client .dot {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

If you were using a CSS preprocessor, like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), you could use:

```
body.page-status .panel.panel-info {
  .server, .client {
    .dot {
      font-size: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe there should be a comma between `.server` and `.client` in your pre-processor example.